# How to find columns that fit an specific range (per individual) and add 1, else 0, using R

Tags: r, range, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with three initial columns: ID, start and end positions.The rest of the columns are numeric chromosomal positions, and it looks like this:

```
ID   start  end  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  ...  n
ind1  2      4   
ind2  1      3
ind3  5      7
```

What I want is to fill out the empty columns (1:n) based on the range for every individual (start:end). For example in the first individual (ind1) the range goes from positions 2 to 4, then those positions fitting the range are filled out with one (1), and those positions out the range with zero (0). To simplify, the desired output should look like this:

```
ID   start  end  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  ...  n
ind1  2      4   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  ...  0 
ind2  1      3   1  1  1  0  0  0  0  ...  0 
ind3  5      7   0  0  0  0  1  1  1  ...  1
```

I will appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you know the number of columns you could use the `between` function from the `data.table` package:

```
cols <- paste0('c',1:7)

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, (cols) := lapply(1:7, function(x) +(between(x, start, end)))][]
```

which gives:

```
     ID start end c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7
1: ind1     2   4  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
2: ind2     1   3  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
3: ind3     5   7  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
```

*Notes*:

- It is better not to name your colummns with just numbers. Therefore I added a `c` at the start of the columnnames.
- Using `+` in `+(between(x, start, end))` is a kind of tric. The more idiomatic way is using `as.integer(between(x, start, end))`.

---

Used data:

```
DF <- read.table(text="ID   start  end
ind1  2      4   
ind2  1      3
ind3  5      7", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks!, it worked quite well, the only additional thing was to make sure start and end values coincides with the cols order.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to begin with the data frame `df`, without the columns already added,

> ```
>     ID start end
> 1 ind1     2   4
> 2 ind2     1   3
> 3 ind3     5   7
> ```

you could do

```
mx <- max(df[-1])
M <- Map(function(x, y) replace(integer(mx), x:y, 1L), df$start, df$end)
cbind(df, do.call(rbind, M))
#     ID start end 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
# 1 ind1     2   4 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 2 ind2     1   3 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
# 3 ind3     5   7 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

The number of new columns will equal the maximum of the `start` and `end` columns.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ind1", "ind2", 
"ind3"), class = "factor"), start = c(2L, 1L, 5L), end = c(4L, 
3L, 7L)), .Names = c("ID", "start", "end"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Nice base R solution!